# Why my UIScrollView become rendering slow after added layer shadow effort to each UIImage which are subviews of my scrollview?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Why my UIScrollView become rendering slow after added layer shadow effort to each UIImage which are subviews of my scrollview?

I try to remove the shadow effort, and the scrollview rendering well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imgView.bounds];
imgView.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```

Comment: Thank you! It work!  However, I added these codes to the imageview of tableviewcell, it can not display the imageview layer shadow. How can I code cell.imageview.layer.shadow in order to display the shadow correctly?

Comment: This code only adds path for shadow so it will be calculated easier. Add all the code you add to your imageViews. If that does not help accept this answer and create new question. Cells of UITableVIew have very complex behavor. Also post your code where (in what method) and how you add shadow to cell's imageView.

Answer (score 2):

you can set like this :layer.shouldRasterize = YES.